# CSS - How can I make a simple navigation menu with submenus?

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS at the moment. I have my navigation menu done, but I have submenus under the main selections. Here is my code:

```
#navigation ul {
    font-family:Arial;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navigation li {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:11px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#navigation a {
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

And here is my HTML (I am making a site on Half Life and Portal to learn):

```
<div id="menus">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Aperture Science</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">GLaDOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testing Chambers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Player (Chell)</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Black Mesa</li>
            <ul>
                <li>The Combine</li>
                <li>The Resistance</li>
                <li>The Player (Gordon Freeman)</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
</div>
```

What do I need to change?

Note: Yes, I haven't finished putting in quick 'a' tags...

Comment: you can refer this http://css3menu.com/

Comment: You can take a look of http://jsfiddle.net/55nw4wmy/ just wrote it for a similar question. Don't close that li `<li><a href="#">Aperture Science</a></li>` too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check code

```css
#menus ul{
    padding:0
}
#menus ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:-2px;
    position:relative;
}
#menus ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menus ul li a:hover{background: #666;}
#menus ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    transition:all .5s; 
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menus  ul.submenu li{
    display:block; 
}
#menus  ul.submenu li a{
    display:block;
    background:blue;
  color: #fff;
}
#menus  ul.submenu li a:hover{background: #333;}
#menus ul li:hover ul{
    max-height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menus">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code---

```
<div id="menus">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css--

```
#menus ul{
    padding:0
}
#menus ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:-2px;
    position:relative;
}
#menus ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:red;
    color:#FFF;
}
#menus ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:0px;
    transition:all .5s;
}
#menus  ul.submenu li{
    display:block;
    transform:scale(0, 1); 
    transition:all .5s;
}
#menus  ul.submenu li:nth-child(2){
    transition-delay:.05s;
}
#menus  ul.submenu li:nth-child(3){
    transition-delay:.1s;
}
#menus  ul.submenu li:nth-child(3){
    transition-delay:.15s;
}
#menus  ul.submenu li:nth-child(4){
    transition-delay:.2s;
}
#menus  ul.submenu li:nth-child(5){
    transition-delay:.25s;
}
#menus ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    width:auto;
}
#menus ul li:hover ul li{
    transform:scale(1, 1);
    transform-origin: right top;
}
```

view the jsfiddle live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/s5qoy4t4/1/)

Comment: Can't. Don't have enough reputation. I would if I could!

Comment: Yes I can. There you go!

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="menus">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Aperture Science</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">GLaDOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testing Chambers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Player (Chell)</a>
                    <ul>
                <li><a href="#">GLaDOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testing Chambers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Player (Chell)</a></li>
            </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Black Mesa</li>
            <ul>
                <li>The Combine</li>
                <li>The Resistance</li>
                <li>The Player (Gordon Freeman)</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#navigation ul {
    font-family:Arial;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navigation li {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:11px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
    position: relative;
}
#navigation a {
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#navigation ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    opocity: 0;  
    display: none;
}
#navigation ul li:hover ul{
    opocity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

SEE DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/j50Lncva/